# Getting scrambled code instead of error page on .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-controller

Whenever a error is thrown during the loading cycle (page load, map request ...) of any of my .Net 4.5 components (controller, webforms ...) I got the following scrambled code:

[image: Scrambled code]

Any exception leads to the above, DB connection time out, route parameter type cast error you name it... Is it caused by the loading event not being followed through due to the exception? How to get it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this was because the exception was thrown in the controller w/o getting caught and handled which prevented the controller from thoroughly processing the request...

Once I set up to catch and handle the exception it's all roses again.

For anyone who is interested in how to properly handle controller exceptions the below makes a good point of reference:
[Exception handling in Controller (ASP.NET MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046351/exception-handling-in-controller-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: This still does not explain why the error is scrambled, or how to fix the scrambling. I noticed that if I send `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`, the error is unscrambled mysteriously.

Comment: @wizulus That header tells the handler that the incoming request is sent via AJAX so the sender expects response that's nothing other than plain text in nature (H5 blob is no exception), hence the base exception handler gets back with the text representation of the error. I am guessing w/o this header the base handler defaults to coughing up something fancy like a binary representation of the exception - say serialized class object?, assume you can consume it given the right interpreter. This might as well be an internal debugging feature that forks from ASP.NET forgot to switch off.

Comment: I think that is the mystery to uncover here. So far, seemingly useless feature is undocumented, or a bug. I don't want to have to write custom error handling to have errors properly reported. Any idea what feature this may be?